# Javascript - fullscreen API exitFullscreen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I try to prevent a webkit issue regarding fullscreen API, when a video or iframe is requested in fullscreen in a DOM already in fullscreen.

Is there a way to exit from fullscreen if a video or iframe is pull in fullscreen in webkit browser. The aim is to simply prevent a fullscreen if a DOM  or the document is already in fullscreen. I try with :

```
document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
document.webkitExitFullscreen();
```

But it's not working. You can observe this bug on this fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/VbfPC/4/
Or in any lightbox plugin using a fullscreen mode for example: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/videos.html

It seems to be a deep issue in webkit browsers. webkitExitFullscreen just doesn't work as espected.

Comment: Your sample worked for me

Comment: It's not working. Look at the video player styles and also the fullscreen state button. Even if nothing is in fullscreen, the HTML5 video player is still in fullscreen. It only happens if you click at first on Launch fullscreen and then on video fullscreen. If you go back (exit fullscreen), webkit browsers just have a big issue and still stay in fullscreen (even if the browser is not in fullscreen).

Comment: It works for me too. I can’t switch the video to full screen while the page is full screen. But there are no troubles leaving full screen and then playing the video in full screen. Probably a bug specific to your version of Safari?

Comment: No, this bug appears in all webkit browsers (Safari, Google Chrome, Opera) on Mac and Windows. To reproducr it, you need to click on "Launch Fullscreen" then on the video fullscreen button, then again on the video fullscreen button and on "Launch Fullscreen". Now, everything looks like to be exit of fullscreen, but it's not the case! Look at the fullscreen buttoin of the video. The icon state is still like in fullscreen because the user agent is still in fullscreen... it's a huge issue. This issue doesn't appear if you use escape.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I experienced the issue with the second example. I needed to click the "exit full screen button" twice.

Comment: And if you debug the style sheet you can clearly see that the ':-webkit-full-screen-ancestor' is still applied on the DIV which was in fullscreen...

Comment: Just FYI Google forked WebKit some time ago and called it Blink, which is nowadays used by Chrome and Opera and is no longer strongly related to WebKit. (So Safari is now the only major browser relying on WebKit). And I can’t reproduce the issue with the fiddle, even after exactly following the steps you described. (Safari 10.0.1)

Comment: On recent version of Safari (or Google Chrome on Mac), you can't simply have a video in fullscreen in a fullscreen DIV because of this issue. But on Google Chrome (or Opera) on window, there is an issue. Is there a way to prevent a fullscreen programmatically?